# Game javascript no Framework cordova ou phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova

Boa tarde, eu criei um joguinho pra web com javascript, quis portar ela para android, depois de pesquisar achei o cordova ou phonegap, que é bem legal, mas quando compilei o game para android a taxa de quadros por segundo fica muito baixa, o jogo não tão pesado e os aparelhos em que testei não são fracos. Percebi que ele fica lento ao interpola a imagem gerada no canvas, não sei se isso tem haver, já vi muitos jogos que são assim e eles funcionam bem, se alguém poder me ajudar fico grato.

Comment: Algo que você pode fazer parar ficar mais performático, é manter apenas três imagens ou a quantidade de imagens necessárias p o seu app, se você ao usar uma imagem deletar provavelmente o erra vai parar de existir. Existem frameworks bons para isso como o Enchant.js, que possívelmente vai facilitar a sua vida.

Answer (score 0):

**Como funciona o cordova/phonegap?**

O funcionamento é bem simples. O cordova nada mais é que um programa instalado no celular que tem um motor de browser embarcado. Quando desenvolvemos um app usando certa tecnologia usando js e HTML o que ocorre no celular ao abrir a aplicação é o mesmo executar a mesma a partir do próprio browser instalado no browser.

**Como é a performance do cordova?**

Como o SO interpreta o cordova como um browser, não é alocado tantos recursos como memória e processamento para a aplicação em questão. E ai está um problema que muitas vezes justifica a não utilização do cordova em uma aplicação.

**Sobre jogos com cordova**

A menos que seja algo relativamente muito simples não recomendo a utilização do cordova. O ideal é desenvolver usando linguagem nativa da plataforma devido a essa questão de alocação de processamento e memória